Calculating some Gaussian ratios
Let $N \geq 1$ be a positive integer, and let $w = (w_1, \dots, w_N)$ denote a positive sequence of real numbers. Let $\{g_n\}_{n \leq N}$ denote a sequence of iid standard Normal random variables.
Question: What is the value of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \leq N}$ given by
$$
a_{n} = \mathbb{E} \Big[\frac{w_n g_n^2}{\sum_{n \leq N} w_n g_n^2}\Big]?
$$
Some obvious observations:

Obviously we have that $\{a_n\}_{n \leq N}$ itself is a positive sequence and moreover it sums to 1.
In the case $N = 1$, $a_1 = 1$.
In the case $N = 2$, by brute force calculations we have
$$
a_1 = \frac{\sqrt{w_1}}{\sqrt{w_1} + \sqrt{w_2}}, \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
a_2 = \frac{\sqrt{w_2}}{\sqrt{w_1} + \sqrt{w_2}}.
$$


By using $\frac{1}{A}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sA}ds$ applied to $A= w_1g_1^2+\cdots+w_ng_n^2$ you reduce the calculation of $a_1$ to the one of a non elementary integral (elliptic for $N=3$ and hyper elliptic after).
